# Is there a better way to catch tweets using Twitter4J?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I tried using the StatusListener and TwitterStream way for a cleaner way to do this, but it seems not to catch all tweets from the users I want.

```
StatusListener statusListener = new StatusListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStatus(Status status) {
        //my code
    }
    //other requiredly-overriden methods
}
ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey("XXXXX");
configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXXXXXX");
TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(configurationBuilder.build()).getInstance(new AccessToken("XXXXX", "XXXXXXX"));
twitterStream.addListener(statusListener);
twitterStream.sample();
```

So I resorted to manually checking every 3 seconds whether a new tweet has been posted by the users I want to. This works perfectly, but seems unclean and hacky. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't fully understand. How are you trying to catch the tweets from the users that you are interested to?. If you were simply using the twitter stream and then checking if a tweet is from the user you want you could get tweets from different sources (and maybe losing some tweets if there are a lot).

If you want to follow some users you should use a filter, like this:

```
StatusListener statusListener = new StatusListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStatus(Status status) {
        //your code to manage the statuses
    }
    //other requiredly-overriden methods
}
ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey("XXXXX");
configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXXXXXX");
TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(configurationBuilder.build()).getInstance(new AccessToken("XXXXX", "XXXXXXX"));
twitterStream.addListener(statusListener);

//from here is different at your code

//you need to set up your user list, with their users id's!
long[] userslist = YOUR USER LIST;
//then you create a filter
FilterQuery filtre = new FilterQuery();
//and use that filter to follow the users that you want and to start the stream
filtre.follow(userslist);
twitterStream.filter(filtre);
```

With the filter you could follow up to 5000 different users and you will get what they tweet, when they are being retweeted and when they are being mentioned

Comment: That's a wonderful idea, I didn't even know there were filters. And I start the stream by using the sample() method, correct?

Comment: No, with sample() you get a sample data from the whole TwitterStream... and that sample is very small. The stream is started with twitterStream.filter(filtre); :)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help. But the stream still picks up tweets in the past, even though I use filterQuery.count(0)...

Comment: I don't know why if you set count(0) you get previous tweets, but you'll eventually get only live tweets in some time